Убрать кавычки из условия WHERE
В мой запрос к БД попадает параметр string, содержащий набор чисел:
where id in ('224994, 226010, 225632, 225730, 225319') 

Каким образом я могу убрать одинарные кавычки непосредственно внутри запроса в Oracle? Я понимаю, что скорее всего необходимо использовать replace, но не понимаю, как экранировать ординарные кавычки.

Убирание кавычек вас не спасет. Покажите что это за строка такая(как определена) и как она добавляется в ваш запрос

Добавляется через сервлет (массивом) и далее параметром string в birt, где сам запрос

Судя по диалекту, это что то на java'вском.? Нужен сам запрос Oracle. Как он там формируется? Если вы где то на уровне сервера приложений сформировали запрос и в таком виде пихаете его на выполнение в Oracle, то на стророне Oracle уже ничего не сделать. В Oracle можно поколдовать, но если запрос собирается именно там.

Попробуй распарсить строку:
WHERE col_id IN (SELECT to_number(regexp_substr(t.val, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS num
                   FROM (SELECT '224994, 226010, 225632, 225730, 225319' val FROM dual) t
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(t.val) - length(REPLACE(t.val, ',', '')) + 1)


действительно не понятен контекст, если запрос выполняется непосредственно на БД оракл, можно использовать динамический SQL:
execute immediate 'select ... where id in (' ||vstring|| ')';
